# How to get file and line number links in tracebacks in PyCharm with remote interpreter?

Tags: python, vagrant, pycharm

When I'm using a local interpreter and there's an exception or error thrown during execution of a python program, there are links to the files and line numbers in the stack trace that's printed in the run window.  When I'm using a remote interpreter (via Vagrant in this case), they're not there.  Is this a missing feature or have I configured PyCharm incorrectly?

Edit: I should add that this is with PyCharm 3.1.1

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? It's annoying me too...

Comment: You might want to add this as a feature request to the [PyCharm tracker](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com)

Answer (score 0):

This feature was added in PyCharm 4.0. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-10224